# What are the available XUL alternatives?

Tags: xul

Are there any XUL alternatives that enable me to write cross platform Javascript Applications ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google Web Toolkit (GWT) doesn't use XUL.

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla's add-on sdk project](http://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk) would allow to you write CommonJS modules that could be used in other contexts. The easiest way to get started using is it is to use the [Add-on Builder](https://builder.mozillalabs.com/).